# R - how to find exact pattern when listing files

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a number of files from which I would like to find only the ones that match an exact pattern.

When I run:

```
mods=c('GISS-E2-H','GISS-E2-R','GISS-E2-R-CC')
files <- list.files(idir, pattern=mods[1])
```

I got the results:

```
> files
[1] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_185001-190012.nc"
[2] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_190101-195012.nc"
[3] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_195101-201012.nc"
[4] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_185001-190012.nc"
[5] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_190101-195012.nc"
[6] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_195101-200512.nc"
```

which is wrong, because I just wanted the last three names (which match the EXACT pattern I wish).

Even if I use regex to create the pattern, I will get a empty vector as result:

```
files <- list.files(idir, pattern=paste("^",m[1],"$", sep=''), full.names=T)
> files
character(0)
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want: `list.files(ldir, pattern = paste0(mod[1], "_"))`

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck, it works exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works, the first three files also have the pattern `GISS-E2-H`.

To get only the last three, you can do as suggested by @G.Grothendieck and add the `_` to mods:

```
mods=c('GISS-E2-H_','GISS-E2-R','GISS-E2-R-CC')
```

Now to test your solution I'll create the files:

```
allfiles <- c("clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_185001-190012.nc",
    "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_190101-195012.nc",
    "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H-CC_historical_r1i1p1_195101-201012.nc",
    "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_185001-190012.nc",
    "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_190101-195012.nc",
    "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_195101-200512.nc")

for (file in allfiles) {
  write("empty file", file)
}
```

Now it works:

```
> list.files(getwd(), pattern=mods[1])
[1] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_185001-190012.nc" "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_190101-195012.nc"
[3] "clt_Amon_GISS-E2-H_historical_r1i1p1_195101-200512.nc"
```

*Edit:*

An alternative is as originally proposed, and instead of replacing `mods` you can append the `_` inside `list.files`:

```
mods=c('GISS-E2-H','GISS-E2-R','GISS-E2-R-CC') #Original
list.files(getwd(), pattern=paste0(mods[1], "_"))
```

I would use this with caution, though. If you turn this into some kind of loop to also read the other file patterns in `mods`, the `_` will be appended to all patterns, making them possibly incorrect.

Comment: My solution appears to be working based on my testing.

Comment: This answer works but I still prefer @G. Grothendieck's approach as it uses the `_` in the `pattern` statement rather than in the variable `mods` (which is coming from other code).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am still (unfortunately) unable to use your solution. It returns `character(0)`.

Comment: @Pascal Did you create the files using the code above? Also please note that on the answer by Tim there's an extra/wrong `d` on the pattern. That should be `_` or nothing.

Comment: @Molx I created files even before your answer. With `_` instead of `d`, it works, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
files <- list.files(idir, pattern = ".*GISS-E2-Hd.*")
```

Your original vector of patterns was this:

```
mods=c('GISS-E2-H','GISS-E2-R','GISS-E2-R-CC')
```

which was trying to match *exactly* files called `GISS-E2-H` etc.  Since those files do not exits in your `idir` you were getting back `character(0)`.

Comment: It seems that the `^` and `$` operators are not allowed in the pattern.

Comment: I think this won't work if it's tested against a string of the file names. Just the string `GISS-E2-H` should work as long as an actual file path is passed to `list.files()`.

Comment: @Molx If I am not mistaken, it is exactly what the OP tried first. And it doesn't work.